# How can I read chainstate database?

Tags: database, utxo

1) What is the format of the LevelDB databases stored in the database directory?

I know there are some custom blockchain parsing libraries, such as [this one](https://code.google.com/p/blockchain/), but I'm wondering if I can just do a read of the chainstate database to get some basic information about the UTXO set.

2) Is there some sort of a LevelDB database explorer GUI that I can use to see what's in this database?

3) Could I have a second program that just read from this database? Would it be safe or would I mess up the database if I tried this?

Comment: https://github.com/hij1nx/levelweb

Answer (score 1):

You can find how to read the blockchain leveldb (format and meaning of the keys) here: [What are the keys used in the blockchain levelDB (ie what are the key:value pairs)?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/28168/what-are-the-keys-used-in-the-blockchain-leveldb-ie-what-are-the-keyvalue-pair)

no idea (yet) for the UTXO :-)

Comment: He talks about the unspent transaction set too. Ctrl-F `Inside the chain state database`

Comment: @Nick, could you elaborate further on how to get the UTXO set from the chainstate database? That sounds like the answer I am looking for. But many other coins don't have the chainstate database, so how would I do this for those coins?

Comment: @StephenM347 I don't think there's any *coin that doesn't have a transaction index or an unspent transaction index. Way too slow. Be more specific.

Comment: In my ~/Application Support/Bitcoin/ directory, there is a chainstate directory, which I think has the database of UTXOs. In my ~/Application Support/PPCoin/ directory, though, there is no chainstate directory. Is the UTXO set stored somewhere else in PPCoin? Can you explain what you mean by "Ctrl-F Inside the chain state database"? Thanks!

Comment: @NickODell means: go to http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/28168/what-are-the-keys-used-in-the-blockchain-leveldb-ie-what-are-the-keyvalue-pair and search the sentence "Inside the chain state database" in your browser. Format of UTXO DB is explained here.

Answer (score 0):

One guy on GitHub said that his software can make chainstate files readable for humans:
https://github.com/in3rsha/bitcoin-utxo-dump