# Where can I query the UTXO database?

Tags: utxo, live-data

Currently there are 35 million unspent transaction outputs. Is there a site somewhere where I can query this data to see, for instance, how many UTXO's exist with a value less than 20,000 satoshis? Or the total unique `scriptPubKey` values found in a  UTXOs?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no such site. You could get this with some coding. For example accessing a node's levelDB; see chainstate db keys in the accepted answer of [this](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/28168/what-are-the-keys-used-in-the-blockchain-leveldb-ie-what-are-the-keyvalue-pair) question.

Answer (score 2):

The standard bitcoind core daemon has no methods to query the UTXO set for reasons I don't know: it should be trivial to give access to it even on a pruned node since it needs to have the full UTXO set at any time to validate a new block.

Anyway a pull request seems in progress to add this capability:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/8952

There are anyway third party apis to query a single address, for example https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/ or https://chain.so/api

Comment: The pull request you refer to improves the `listunspent` RPC, which queries the wallet. It does not give you access to the network-side UTXO set. The does exist a `gettxout` RPC, however.

Comment: Thanks, I misinterpreted. Anyway I'm still at a loss in understanding why there is no way to query the UTXO.
A simple command to check if tx/index is in the UTXO would be a great start, for example.

Comment: That exists, it is called `gettxout`.

Comment: @AlessandroPolverini did you find the answer to your question?

Comment: No, I haven't find any method to list all the UTXO: you already have to know it to query one out of a tx.