# latest UTXO databases received

Tags: blockchain, utxo

There are many repositories that allow you to turn blockchain into UTXO. But I can't find where I could download ready-made UTXOs. I only find instructions on how to get such a database myself. Bitcoin Core predicted that it would take 55 hours to download the database, which is certainly a lot, so I'd like to ask if you know any repositories where they put the latest UTXO databases received?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to download a "recent" UTXO set snapshot?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/53865/what-is-the-best-way-to-download-a-recent-utxo-set-snapshot)  -- Note that the UTXO set has to be updated every 10 minutes or so and that you can't trust a UTXO set that you haven't created from blocks you have verified yourself.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick
I saw this post from 2017. I'm not chasing an up-to-date base, so even a week (month) old base would be fine with me.

Comment: They also suggested downloading UTXOS from Electrum, but how do I do that? I couldn't find anything...

Comment: You could ask a friend who uses Bitcoin Core to give you a copy of their [chainstate folder](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Core_0.11_(ch_2):_Data_Storage) - but you'd have to extract data from the [LevelDB data structure](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/28168/13866). Electrum might also have some persistent data storage that mainly consists of UTXO data.