# How to get raw block data?

Tags: bitcoin-core, block, raw-data

I can use `getblock` json rpc method to get parsed block details, however I need the actual raw data.

Is there any way to get raw block data using Bitcoin Core?

Comment: You can read it directly from the blk*.dat files...

Comment: So to implement such method as getrawblock I need to create my own index with filename and offset for each block, right?

Comment: In principle you can use the existing leveldb database in the `blocks/index` directory to locate the block data within the blk*.dat file by its hash.  See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Core_0.11_(ch_2):_Data_Storage or https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/28168/what-are-the-keys-used-in-the-blockchain-leveldb-ie-what-are-the-keyvalue-pair for the data format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a boolean parameter to that RPC call that'll return it as a hex string representing the binary contents of the block.

> If verbosity is 0, returns a string that is serialized, hex-encoded data for block 'hash'

`getblock 'hash' 0` should return what you want.