# Regarding the chainstate level db (UXTO)

Tags: blockchain, leveldb

Already found many useful information regarding the chainstats db.

such as:
[What are the keys used in the blockchain levelDB (ie what are the key:value pairs)?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/28168/what-are-the-keys-used-in-the-blockchain-leveldb-ie-what-are-the-keyvalue-pair)

But what is the meanning of the last item?

```
'B' -> 32-byte block hash: the block hash up to which the database represents the unspent transaction outputs.
```

Is that means there is a row in the db, which key is a constant 'B' and value is the latest block hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that means there is a row in the db, which key is a constant 'B' and value is the latest block hash?

Correct.